# Can CSS be over ridden on Android the same way userContent.css works on Firefox?

Tags: browser, applications

This is related to another question I posed recently, but I thought I should keep issues separate and specific.

On a desktop computer running Firefox, one can create a file called "userContent.css" and have the CSS in that file over ride the CSS for specific web sites.

I'd like to be able to do the same thing on my Android 2.2 phone, especially since there are so many sites not optimized for mobile viewing.

I am agnostic about how this is done, whether it's an app, or a setting in the Android default browser, or something else.

PS: I've tried downloading the Firefox beta for my phone (HTC Magic), but it seems that it is not available for my model.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You may want to try again now with the newest version of Firefox.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version, and I also have a newer more capable phone (Samsung Galaxy S 2). However, I am at a loss as to whether it is possible to put a userContent.css file somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to apply a user stylesheet with the default Android browser.

If you Firefox isn't available on your phone, you could install the APK manually, but it may not work since it isn't supported.

You could download the Opera browser, connect it to [remote debugging using the Dragonfly debugger](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/remote-debugging-with-opera-dragonfly/), and then manually apply the stylesheet via debugging--but there are a lot of steps to that and you would have to add the stylesheet on every page load. This may not be a solution depending on what your needs are for the user stylesheet.

Comment: Since asking this question, I have upgraded to a phone that does support Firefox. Is there userChrome capability on Firefox for Android?

Comment: @DaveMG: According to bugzilla, there's no mention of it for Firefox on Android. So I don't know. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?short_desc=userchrome&op_sys=Android&query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&product=Firefox

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways for something similar

1. if all you want is black background and white text for absolutely all sites, go to about:config and disable use page colors. then set background and foreground colors to what you want.
2. if you require a more complex stylesheet, install stylish add on, and either use your css locally or upload to the site the extension uses.

case 1 will be crappy for forms. for some reason forms and the screens like add on screen or the annoying and useless mandatory home screen are not affected. forms are affected by option 2, but add on and home screen, again, are not.